# How Can I Implement Multiple Routes in HereMaps?

Tags: ios, here-api, here-ios

How can I implement multiple routes using the iOS `HereMap` SDK.
Can anyone provide the Example for the Multiple routes.

Comment: How many routes you want?

Comment: 3 routes if available

Comment: By this example I'm  able to create one route https://github.com/heremaps/here-ios-sdk-examples/blob/master/routing-ios-swift/RoutingApp/MapViewController.swift

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Lite Variant (4.x) of the SDK, set alternativeRoutes in the Route options: https://developer.here.com/documentation/ios-sdk/api_reference/Structs/RouteOptions.html

In the Premium SDK (3.x), set alternatives routes in the NMAroutingMode, and it's called a bit differently there: ResultLimit
See https://developer.here.com/documentation/ios-premium/api_reference_jazzy/Classes/NMARoutingMode.html#%2Fc:objc(cs)NMARoutingMode(py)resultLimit

Comment: Still unclear which product/variant/version you are using, but your example above with one route should be easy to adapt. Just set the alternative routes to 1 or higher (max. 9), and route result (what is anyway already an array) will contain the routes, if available.